Dependency Array of useCallback is not working
I have a useCallback function and a snackbar state, each time deleteRow function called, snackbar state will be updated, but setSnackbar function not update the first value that we pass, so when we log from snackbar, snackbar doesn't have the all value that we pass into it
const deleteRow = useCallback(async (item: ICheckoutItem, ppid: number, isLastOne = false) => {
        let newItems = [...checkoutItems];
        newItems = newItems.map(((item) => {
            item.properties = item.properties.filter((property) => property.id !== ppid);
            return item;
        }));

        newItems = newItems.filter((item) => item.properties.length > 0);

        setCheckoutItems(newItems);

        await server_axios.delete(endpoints.orderProductProperties.delete(ppid) + (orderId ? `?order_id=${orderId}` : ''));

        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

        if (isLastOne && type === 'edit') {
            enqueueSnackbar(
                `تمامی کالاهای پروفیل ${item.product.name} با موفقیت حذف شدند.\nهمچنین وضعیت سفارش شما به «حذف‌شده» تغییر داده شد.`,
                {
                    variant: 'multiline',
                    color: 'info',
                }
            );
            console.log(snackbar)
            snackbar.forEach((id) => {
                closeSnackbar(id)
            })
            setSnackbar([])
        } else if (!isLastOne) {
            const esId: SnackbarKey = enqueueSnackbar('کالای مورد نظر با موفقیت حذف شد.', {
                color: 'info',
                variant: 'myCustomVariant',
                showTimer: true,
                showButton: true,
                autoHideDuration: 10 * 1000,
                onClick: async () => {
                    await server_axios.patch(endpoints.orderProductProperties.cancel_delete(ppid))
                    if (onRefresh) onRefresh();
                }
            })
            setSnackbar(currentSnackbar => {
                console.log('Previous snackbar state:', currentSnackbar);
                console.log('New snackbar ID:', esId);
                const newState = [...currentSnackbar, esId];
                console.log('New snackbar state:', newState);
                return newState;
            });
            // updateSnack(esId)
            // console.log(esId)
            // let newSnackbar = snackbar.length ? [...snackbar, esId] : [esId]
            // console.log(newSnackbar)
            // setSnackbar([...newSnackbar])
        }

        if (afterUpdate) afterUpdate((newItems.length === 0));

    }, [checkoutItems, orderId, type, snackbar]);


The problem is not with useCallback. It's simply that const snackbar won't change while the async function is running - setSnackbar will update the component state and cause it to re-render with a new value (and a new deleteRow function), but none of that affects the value in the running function.

The issue here is that snackbar might not have the latest state when deleteRow runs because of how React handles state in closures.
To fix this, try using a functional update with setSnackbar, which ensures you always have the latest snackbar state:
setSnackbar((currentSnackbar) => {
    currentSnackbar.forEach((id) => closeSnackbar(id));
    return [];
});

Also, remove snackbar from the dependency array in useCallback, since using the functional updater means you don’t need it as a dependency. This should stop the page from resetting and keep your focus where it should be.
here is the full example:
const deleteRow = useCallback(async (item: ICheckoutItem, ppid: number, isLastOne = false) => {
    let newItems = [...checkoutItems];
    newItems = newItems.map((item) => {
        item.properties = item.properties.filter((property) => property.id !== ppid);
        return item;
    });

    newItems = newItems.filter((item) => item.properties.length > 0);
    setCheckoutItems(newItems);

    await server_axios.delete(endpoints.orderProductProperties.delete(ppid) + (orderId ? `?order_id=${orderId}` : ''));
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    if (isLastOne && type === 'edit') {
        enqueueSnackbar(
            `تمامی کالاهای پروفیل ${item.product.name} با موفقیت حذف شدند.\nهمچنین وضعیت سفارش شما به «حذف‌شده» تغییر داده شد.`,
            {
                variant: 'multiline',
                color: 'info',
            }
        );
        
        // Close all snackbars based on the latest state of `snackbar`
        setSnackbar((currentSnackbar) => {
            currentSnackbar.forEach((id) => closeSnackbar(id));
            return [];
        });

    } else if (!isLastOne) {
        const esId: SnackbarKey = enqueueSnackbar('کالای مورد نظر با موفقیت حذف شد.', {
            color: 'info',
            variant: 'myCustomVariant',
            showTimer: true,
            showButton: true,
            autoHideDuration: 10 * 1000,
            onClick: async () => {
                await server_axios.patch(endpoints.orderProductProperties.cancel_delete(ppid));
                if (onRefresh) onRefresh();
            }
        });

        setSnackbar((currentSnackbar) => {
            const newState = [...currentSnackbar, esId];
            console.log('New snackbar state:', newState);
            return newState;
        });
    }

    if (afterUpdate) afterUpdate(newItems.length === 0);

}, [checkoutItems, orderId, type, afterUpdate, onRefresh]);

